# JavaScript: Error - "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jslint

I am using [JSLint](http://JSLint.com) to ensure my JavaScript is "strict" and I'm getting the following error:

> Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

On the following code:

```
(my_var > 0 ) ? $("#abc").html(my_array.join('')) : $("#abc").html('<h2>Hello ' + persons_name);
```

Any ideas why I'm getting such an error? Also, I'm using jQuery as seen in the above code, in case that makes a difference.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My guess would be that JSLint is unhappy since you're using the ternary operator, and you're not doing anything with the value. Refactoring this into the equivalent:

```
if (my_var > 0 ) {
  $("#abc").html(my_array.join(''));
} else {
  $("#abc").html('<h2>Hello ' + persons_name);
}
```

would eliminate the error. If for some reason you're really attached to using the ternary operator, the "right" way to use it would be:

```
$("#abc").html((my_var > 0) ? my_array.join('') : '<h2>Hello ' + persons_name);
```

Comment: I wish there were a relaxing option for using bitwise && as bool type checks

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is because the ternary operator evaluates the expression and returns a value that is expected to be assigned.  For example:

```
var test = (my_var > 0) ? true : false;
```

However, you are using it like a regular if/then/else statement.  While the ternary operator does perform if/then/else, it is traditionally used in assignents.

EDIT: As an addendum: would this statement make sense to you?

```
var foo = 1;
(my_var > 0) ? true : false;
console.log('hello world');
```

Answer (score 2):

you are using an expression (an expression using the ternary operator to be precise) in a single line: your line is comprised uniquely of an expression.

this is considered poor programming practice in many language, and could be rewritten using an `if` statement to render this line more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Just asked the same Q without finding this one for some reason...

The ternary returns a value that isn't being used so you're abusing the ternary structure by not using the value (even though the function calls are being made as intended).